# How to allow greater than and less than in sqldatasource string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid, sqldatasource

I'm using a RadGrid and an SqlDataSource to make select, insert and update statements over a database table.

There is a string parameter in which I need to write down texts including tags, for example:

```
"Name: <Name>, Address: <address>".
```

I'm having the problem that the SqlDataSource prevents the use of greater than ">" and less than "<" characters in the attribute values.

How can I achieve the SqlDataSource parameters allow me to use the greater than and less than characters?

Comment: This is not a problem with SqlDataSource -- this is part of the XML standard

Comment: Any idea of what could i do?

Comment: Maybe you choose tokens other than Lt/gt. Like buckets [] or hashes. Something less dangerous

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - none of those would work, this is XML

Answer (score 2):

Try using the HTML tag.

```
&gt; = >
&lt; = <
```

Comment: Where to do this replacement? I was trying to do it at the ItemCommand event of the radgrid but it's not even getting there.

Comment: This won't work, you need a `;` sufix.  Also, these are not "tags" they are called "entities"

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the semicolons.  Replace your 'greater than' and 'less than' symbols with these equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the follow according to XML specifications.  I'm not clear why this would be part of a data source and I suspect the real answer would be different if I knew what you were actually doing.

```
"Name: &lt;Name&gt;, Address: &lt;address&gt;".
```

Comment: The field on the database represents the body of an email the App has to send. The user can configure the value of the field using tags like "<name>" or "<date>" which will be replaced with the right values according to the tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "the field on the database".  This does not make sense using any DB terminology I've ever heard.

Comment: the column on a table of the database, sorry.

Comment: I see.  This is not the kind of data to store in a string field of an XML document.  You want to use CDATA or an actual XML template.

Comment: The solution (so far) was to set validateRequest to false even if it is "risky".

Comment: Validate what request? No idea what you are talking about.